# What constitutes an expensive method or resource?

Tags: c#

It is mentioned fairly often that exceptions are expensive, and various methods in .NET are expensive, too.

What exactly constitutes an expensive method in .NET?

Is it the time taken for the method to process? E.G. I got the response stream of a webpage using the WebClient object (this was not async), and when getting the response and assigning it to a variable, it took a while to step through this line of code. Perhaps because the webpage itself was graphic intensive and large. To see the time taken, I am aware I can use a stopwatch or timer (there is a subtle difference between the two which I can't remember).

Or is it the resources taken? If so, what is the best way of seeing the resources a method takes? I know I can use one of the GC methods, or a profiler. What other approaches are there?

Comment: Side note: The cost of .NET Exceptions is often exagerated by several orders of magnitude. Unless you're throwing thousands of them every second, there's no need to worry about them.

Answer (score 9):

Expensive is a matter of degrees and context.

I work in image processing and I consider division expensive.  In my case, any operation that ends up being performed two to 5 million times in one loop adds up.  This may be the difference between 1/8 of a second and 1/32 of a second.  1/8 of a second in UI time is a lot for a dynamic display.  1/32 is acceptable.

In other cases, it could be full decoding of large JPEG images and scaling them down instead of taking advantage of power of 2 scaled down versions also encoded in the same file.

In web page time, it might be the number of server hits on a page load.  See what I mean?

Context is everything.

Resources are considered expensive if they are scarce and cause other things to wait.  If you have 1 non-raid disk, you pay a heavy price on access if two processes are bouncing the head all over the place, hence the heavy reliance on caching both on the drive and in the OS.

Your printer is a very expensive resource, especially if it's out of paper, hence the queue.

Exceptions are expensive when compared with other language features.  Static method invocation is cheap.  Plain method invocation is slightly more expensive.  Virtual method invocation is slightly more expensive.  Exceptions are much more costly.

For example, you could complain the C# doesn't have type-strong polymorphic return types, and I could say - oh no, it does - just throw your result and catch the right type on the other side.  Then I'd get laughed out of the room for making the suggestion.  Compared with a return (which is a scant few instructions), an Exception may cause dozens to hundreds, depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when people talk about functions being expensive, they typically mean in terms of execution time. (The price you pay for calling it is that your thread gets blocked for X microseconds until the function call completes, after all)

Of course, it might also be expensive in terms of resource usage, but usually, it's execution time that people refer to.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you have both types of expensive operations.

I personally use ANTs Profiler by RedGate to mointor both the time and memory aspects of application events and the cost.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with plint, but I would like to add that expensive usually implies that something takes more time or resources than you would expect, or more resources than you need for a given situation. In general, something is expensive if there is an alternative that uses less cpu or resources that is more appropriate.

For example, exceptions are considered expensive because of the amount of clock cycles it takes to construct a stack trace. Therefore, it's a very bad idea to use exceptions as a flow control mechanism. So, if you were parsing a custom data format and it was malformed, it would probably be better to return an object with a failure status and string (malformed data line 6, pos 3), rather than throw a MalformedDataException.

But yes, expensive is a matter of degree and perspective. To a CPU designer, a cache miss is disasterous. To plint, division is expensive. For me, harddisk access is expensive.